# Facebook comments accessible fallback

Tags: facebook, comments

I want to start using facebook comments on my site.  The problem with them is that they are JavaScript based so users without JS will not be able to comment.

As commenting is one of the core functions of my site I need to provide some form of accessible fallback.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will never be able to fully mix and match. Even if you create a fallback system, the comments will be out of sync with the third party system you are suggesting using.

You will need to evaluate what is more valuable to use, the benefits of using a third party plugin like that or the inaccesability to a small portion of your readership. How many people really have javascript turned off these days? Not many. Is accessing your sites main content enough for them or are comments really your bread and butter?